# Connecting to Azure Service Bus with Listen permission results in error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have two Azure environments, Test and Acceptance. Both have the exact same Topics and Subscriptions, only the namespace (and therefor URL) is different.

On the testing environment I used Management credentials to connect, which works perfectly and I was able to listen to the subscription for new events. On the acceptance environment I created credentials with Listen only permissions, which I'd say is meant for this exact use-case, however it returned in the following error:

```
Service Bus messaging entity '<entity>' or namespace '<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net' not found.\r\nclientRequestId: <reference>
```

The two environments are exactly the same, and connecting with management credentials to the acceptance environment works perfectly as well (to exclude any possible typo mistakes).

Answer (score 1):

There are three type of permissions available for Service Bus Namespaces,

- Manage
- Send
- Listen

With the Manage permission, using the credential, CRUD operations and message processing can be done to the entity.

With Send and Listen permissions, only message processing can be done with the entity (i.e.) create, read, update, delete operations can not be performed, only messages can be sent or received from the entity.

Thus, when you try to fetch the entity using the send or listen credential, it will return the not found error.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, but one way I could use this would be through Azure Logic Apps, which supports connecting to a Service Bus and listening for messages and turning them to webhooks (for example). It sounds reasonable that this would be achievable with Listen only permissions, right?

Comment: Yeah, that is achievable with listen only permission:)

Comment: Then the question would be: What am I doing wrong :-)

Comment: May be the logic app tries to fetch the entity before creating the listener. It may be a bug in logic app.

Comment: It does in fact seem to be something within Azure Logic Apps in case anyone runs into the same.